# nsdate format to last digit in year, then day of year

Tags: nsdateformatter

The following code will output this (current day is `Jan 15, 2015`):

```
2015015
```

I need it to output this:

```
5015
```

I want it in the format of `yddd`, where `y` is the last number in the year, and `ddd` is the day of the year. so `January 1st, 2000` is `0001` and `December 31st, 2007` is `7365`.

```
NSDate *julianLabel = [NDDate date];
NSDateFormatter *julianFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[julianFormatter setDateFormat:@"yddd"];
self.julian.text = [julianFormatter stringFromDate:julianLabel];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you could just use `substringFromIndex` on the string, something that should work for the next eight thousand years or so <sup>(a)</sup>. In other words, something like:

```
self.julian.text = [[julianFormatter stringFromDate:julianLabel] substringFromIndex:3];
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It'll work as per your *specification* until we reach the year 10,000 but keep in mind you'll start getting duplicates in 2025. I'm assuming that's not a problem due to the detail provided.

Comment: too easy, still trying to learn all the objective-c methods. thank you!

Comment: unfortunately i am still new to SO and only have 1 reputation. i need 15 to be able to vote.